# How to compare two list of dictionaries for the key exist in one and not in another

Tags: python

- I have 2 list of dictionary
- parent list `pa = [{'key1': '1A', 'key2': 2},{'key1': '1B', 'key3': 2},{'key1': '1C', 'key4': 2}]`
- child list `ch = [{'key1': '1A', 'keyvalue2': 2},{'key1': '1B', 'keyvalue23': 2},{'key1': '1D', 'key4': 2}]`
- I need to get the `key1` which is present in `pa` and not in `ch`

Code is below

```
for each in pa:
    for each_1 in ch:
        if each['key1'] not in each_1['key1']:
            print(each['key1'])
```

My out is

```
1A
1A
1B
1B
1C
1C
1C
```

My expected out is `1C` which present in `pa` and not in `ch`

I have created two list and compare which is working. but it's not the case like code below. I  don't want to create a extra space

```
pa_list = []
for each in pa:
  if each['key1'] not in pa_list:
    pa_list.append(each['key1'])

ch_list = []
for each in ch:
  if each['key1'] not in ch_list:
    ch_list.append(each['key1'])

[i for i in pa_list if i not in ch_list]
```

Comment: `dict` has a method called `keys` which returns a view (a `set`) of its keys that you could union/diff from the other `dict`.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley - Not quite, but very good idea  You need to convert keys() view to a set first: `set({1:1}.keys()).union(set({2:2}.keys()))`

Comment: @BrianMcFarland You do not.  `dict_keys` is a `set`-like, so you can use it as a `set` directly: `pa.keys() - ch.keys()` to find the keys in `pa` that aren't in `ch`.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley - TIL `+` & `-` operators for `set`-likes, thanks!  As far as I can tell, `{}.keys.difference` etc for named set methods still don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your original code, I suggest you to use the **for/else** loop, not very well-known, but quite useful in your case:

```
pa = [{'key1': '1A', 'key2': 2},{'key1': '1B', 'key3': 2},{'key1': '1C', 'key4': 2}]
ch = [{'key1': '1A', 'keyvalue2': 2},{'key1': '1B', 'keyvalue23': 2},{'key1': '1D', 'key4': 2}]

for i in pa:
    for j in ch:
        if (i['key1'] == j['key1']):
            break
    else:
        print(i['key1'])
```

It outputs only '1C' without intermediate variable, as expected.